# some weather forecast terms

Tags: translation

I'm translating some russian weather forecast related phrases to english, but I'm not sure whether those are right

```
Sudden temperature changes. Not a good day for a walk.

Storm warning. Don't forget to take an umbrella.

Ordinary day(calm day?)

Rainy Season

No precipitation
```

Are those terms used in such a way in english?

Comment: I think you should be clearer on what the term is you're wanting to use and under what type of circumstance you wish to use it. Certainly 'storm warning' would mean far more than 'take an umbrella'.

Comment: @GrahamNicol I mean in russian "storm warning" literary doesn't mean actual storm

Comment: To address your question, I'd suggest you look at some forecasts in English and familiarise yourself with the usual terminology.  For example, as I understand it, sudden *temperature* changes are often the result of sudden *pressure* changes, usually caused by a [**front**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_front) - a term you will often hear in forecasts (NB I Am Not A Meteorologist).

Comment: This might not be the best place for you to get the information you're asking for. Unless someone on here has the technical knowledge about weather forecasting terms we probably won't be able to help you. Perhaps look up some government meteorology sites (UK, US, Australia etc) and see if they have a list of terms and defintions.

Comment: this is the [BBC's UK weather forecast for today](http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast-video/21416743) if that's any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sudden temperature changes. Not a good day for a walk.

Sudden temperature changes are most commonly associated with a [*cold front*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_front).  However, the phrase "sudden temperature change" is very general and could also be associated with many weather phenomena, including *warm fronts* and [*chinook winds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinook_wind).

> Storm warning. Don't forget to take an umbrella.

In English, *storm warning* usually refers to one of several more specific warnings: *severe thunderstorm warning*, *tornado warning*, *flood warning*, and *hurricane warning*, for example.  In each case, the word *warning* is used to indicate that a serious weather event has been identified by authorities and that it is imminent.  A meteorologist (in the US at least) would not simply say *storm warning* to mean that "a storm is likely today."  Instead they would say "scattered thunderstorms likely" or "afternoon thundershowers expected."

> Ordinary day(calm day?)

Neither of these two options is frequently used.  *Calm* refers specifically to [very light winds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaufort_scale), and *ordinary* does not mean anything when it comes to weather.  The best option is likely *fair weather*, indicating sun and relatively comfortable temperatures.  For reference to the skies only, you can use *fair skies*, indicating sun and nothing more than a few clouds, as well as *sunny* and *partly cloudy*.

> Rainy Season

This is fine.  In some places it's referred to as the [*monsoon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsoon).

> No precipitation

This is fine to say as part of sentences like "No precipitation is expected today," especially when the temperatures are in the range where rain, sleet, or snow is possible.

Comment: "Ordinary day" may be replaced by "*seasonal weather*".